# Test ads are shown in real device but not in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, admob, adb

The emulator was working perfectlty showing test ads but in the last 2 days the test ads are not shown in the emulator. It is not a problem of the code because before it was showing the test ads and I have not changed the implementation of the ads, but now they are not shown in the emulator but they continue to be shown in a real device. What could be happening with the emulator?

Edit: The internet connection is still working fine because if I search something on Google in the emulator it is working fine.

Edit2: I have tried to log the ad when it is loaded and suddenly after waiting 2 minutes the log has appeared and the ads are shown. Why it has take so long to load the ad in the emulator but in a real device it just takes some seconds?

Answer (score 1):

try logging to be sure, since ad mob has AdListener, u can easily log them

Comment: I don´t understand anything, I have logged it when the ad is loaded, and after 2 min the log has appeared and it is working fine. It is like if in the emulator the ad is loaded really slowly and in a real device the ad is loaded faster...